# Collective word for these people

Tags: vocabulary, collective-nouns

I am looking for a word to describe people such as barber, ironsmith, tailor, carpenter etc. People with miscellaneous specialty who would move to a village to serve others who are normally into agriculture. Any ideas?

Comment: Depending on the domain, area of business, etc., different terms are employed, including *skilled worker, artisan, tradesman, technician, smith, wright, artificer,* etc.

Comment: If you are writing a story ... Guildsman - the bunching of skilled labour into a collective. Frequently, such collectives are monopolising collectives. Guildsmen provide services no others can provide and none other  allowed to provide unless being part of the fascist (Italian for *bunching*) socialist collective.

Comment: @BlessedGeek Thank you! I am translating a book from my native language into English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*Tradespeople*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/tradespeople) should suit your need.

Comment: Also _craftsmen_ (or _craftsfolk_).

Comment: Yeah, 40 years ago they would have been "tradesmen", but now "tradespeople".

Comment: @HotLicks "40 years ago they would have been *tradesmen* , **then** *tradespeople* , **now** (as always,) *tradesmen* , which was never incorrect in the first place. :)

Comment: What's not right about all the other synonyms?

Comment: Is there a rant on the goodol days goinonin here?

Answer (score 2):

***Artisans*** might be another possibility.